# HP ALM stuck with status "Waiting for Unified Functional Testing..."

Tags: hp-uft, alm, hp-alm, microfocus

I'm trying to execute the tests in HP ALM, but it always gets stuck and shows the status:

> Waiting for Unified Functional Testing...`

as shown here:

[image: Waiting for Unified Functional Testing...]

The test never begins, and it will just wait like that forever.

I can open UFT individually and execute a test script without a problem. The issue only happens when I execute a test from HP ALM.

I've tried to reinstall both HP ALM & UFT, but the same issue still happens.

Please let me know what else can I do?

Comment: This might be related to User Account Control - try to disable it. Here is also an installation guide for UFT which might be helpful: https://softwaresupport.softwaregrp.com/doc/KM02208499?fileName=UFT12.53_InstallGuide_pdf.pdf

Comment: If you use RndRange, remote test execution deinitialization becomes unstable, trashing the next test instance